# Connecting Cloudera Manager (6.3) to Oracle ATP on OCI using an Oracle Wallet

Tags: jdbc, oracle-call-interface, cloudera-manager, oracle-wallet

I am trying to set up a Cloudera Cluster (Cloudera 6.3) on OCI and want to use an ATP (also running on OCI) as the DB for the Cloudera Manager (I am using these [docs](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/prepare_cm_database.html)).

In order to connect to the ATP I downloaded the wallet, but don’t know how to set the right configurations for the Cloudera Manager so that it uses the wallet with the JDBC Driver (12.2).

I modified the class path in the script scm_prepare_database.sh for when the connection is tested to include all necessary jars for the JDBC Driver, as described in this [document](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/atp-cloud/atpug/connect-jdbc-thin-wallet.html#GUID-32A48CAA-89AC-40A4-AFD1-BB962C562805) and set these properties when executing the script:

- databaseType: `oracle`
- hostname: tried `jdbc:oracle:thin:@<name>_medium`,
  `jdbc:oracle:thin:` and `@<name>_medium`
- databaseName: `<name>_medium`
- databaseUser: `my_username`
- password: `my_password`

However, I always receive the following error: `IO Error: could not resolve the connect identifier “//<hostname>/<my_username>”`

I verified that I can connect from the cluster to the ATP by following the steps described in the linked document.

Is it possible to use a wallet to connect the Cloudera Manager to an Oracle DB (ATP) and if so, what would be the necessary steps to get it working?

I really appreciate your help!

Best regards,
Nils

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC driver version and JDK version is very important. You can either use JKS or Oracle Wallets.

Can you go through the [ATP using 12.2 JDBC driver](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc-eecloud-3089380.html) and the [SSL blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc%2C-tlsv12%2C-jks-or-oracle-wallets) for the detailed instructions?

Comment: These instructions are similar to the ones I followed and are successful in showing that I can connect to the ATP from the cluster.
However, they don't explain how I can set the right parameters to configure the Cloudera Manager. In the setup guide (linked in post) it is explained that you have to use the scm_prepare_database.sh script to configure everything, but I couldn't yet figure out what properties need to be set with this script in order to use an Oracle Wallet.